# Build error when trying to Run basic activity

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, build-error

I'm on day 1 of learning Android Studio / Kotlin and working my way through the (official?) [tutorials](https://developer.android.com/courses/android-basics-kotlin/course).

Having added some basic views to an empty layout and resolved a couple of "coding practice" warnings, when I try to run the app on a USB connected tablet, I get a build failed message.
(I haven't got as far as any Kotlin coding yet.)
I'm completely out of my depth at this stage and can't find a solution that isn't beyond my level of understanding.

The errors are ...

> Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: kotlin/reflect/full/KClasses
>
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: kotlin.reflect.full.KClasses

If there's any other information worth sharing, I'm afraid I don't know what it is at the moment.
ANy suggestions on what I need to do to or investigate to resolve the build fail?

First build.gradle file:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = "1.5.10"
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.2"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter() // Warning: this repository is going to shut down soon
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Second build.gradle file:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.test04"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:2.0.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

Comment: Did you very recently download Android Studio, and is your project one that you created using New Project in Android Studio? The problem seems to be that your project has a dependency on a library that uses Kotlin reflection, but the Kotlin reflection library is not in your project dependencies. I'm not sure how that could happen if you haven't been messing with your `build.gradle` files or adding dependencies.

Comment: Thanks.
Yes, it's a recent download of AS, and the project was created from New Project.
I'm not aware of having done either of the things you mention.
As I haven't got very far at all, is it simplest to uninstall and reinstall AS?

Comment: You should not need to uninstall. Try creating a new project and running it without changing anything. If that doesn't work, please post the text of the two `build.gradle` files in your project and tell us the Android Studio version and which project template you're using.

Comment: Thanks.
Android Studio version is 4.2.2
I'm using the "empty activity" as a starting point. (I assume that's what you mean by template.)
Where do I find the build.gradle files?

Comment: In the top left where it lists the files of your project, expand Gradle Scripts. There should be two different files named `build.gradle`.

Comment: Sorry for the delay responding to this ... 
build.gradle files now added to original question.

Answer (score 0):

Try these steps.

1. Update your Kotlin version from `"1.5.10"` to the latest `"1.5.31"` in your first `build.gradle` file. Also update the Kotlin plugin: **File -> Settings -> Languages and Frameworks -> Kotlin** and if there's a new version there will be an **Install** button to click. Then restart Android Studio and run your project to see if it will work.
2. If that doesn't work, you can manually add the missing reflection library to your project. I don't see in your dependencies anything that uses reflection, but maybe I'm missing something. So, add this line into the `dependencies` section of your second `build.gradle` file:

   `implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect"`

   Then click the "Sync Project with Gradle Files" button near the right end of the toolbar (elephant with blue arrow icon), and try running your project again.
3. The Android Build Tools you're using is also out of date. I'm not sure it could be related, but you can update that as well in the first `build.gradle` file. Change the 4.2.2 to 7.0.3 and click the Gradle sync button again. Android Studio might complain that you need to update your Gradle version, so click yes if it offers to update it for you.